# Automatically add a group of tags to NEW wordpress posts

Tags: wordpress, tags

I have a blog where I make alot of posts every day. Many of the posts use 5 of 10 commonly used tags. Instead of writing out each of these tags every time, I'd rather just uncheck a few of the tags I don't need (and then add any new, or uncommon tags that I have).

So, I'm looking to edit my functions.php document so that any NEW posts will already have a list of 10 tags in it. And, if tags already exists, don't do anything. I'd like to avoid using a plugin, if possible.

Anyone know how to do this? This would be extremely useful.

The code would look something like:
(note: my programming skills are horrendous, so this may not be right, or even possible)

```
function default_tag_list() {
    if(new_post() && !get_the_tag_list()) { // using new_post() ... not sure how to check if its a new post.
        $default_tags = array('health', 'nutrition', 'diet', 'well-being', 'eating');
        return $default_tags; 
    }  // Then, somehow get the get_tag_list in the administration to use the default tags function (if it's a new post without any tags) ...
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Just copy and paste the below code in your function.php :

```
function my_data_update () {
    GLOBAL $post;
    wp_set_post_tags( $post->ID, 'health, nutrition, diet, well-being, eating', true );
}
add_action('publish_post', 'my_data_update');
add_action('save_post', 'my_data_update');
```

this code will definitely work for you as it is tested.

Comment: This works, but is missing some of the functionality that I need. 
First, the function adds the tags to EVERY post you publish. I want to be able to remove the tags, if necessary (so, if I create a post, and delete some of the tags, they get added back to the post when it's published again).
Second, when you create a new post, the new tags aren't listed on the edit page already... you need to click PUBLISH. And, even then, it doesn't show up on the updated edit page. You have to leave the EDIT page, and then go back to it, and then the tags are there.

Comment: Just remove last line of code that is : 
add_action('save_post', 'my_data_update'); it will resolve your first issue. Now for your second issue we need to publish post to add the tags and refresh the page to watch them added. Don't worry they are added as you click on publish button.

Comment: I got rid of the last line ... but it is still adding back in any of the tags that I removed.